# Navigation drawer - top fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have Navigation drawer and a series of fragments. On last fragment of hierarchy, i've got UP button on action bar. As this button clicked, onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) of root activity is called, where i can find out, which button is clicked in the following predicate :

```
    else if ( item.getItemId() ==  android.R.id.home )
    {
        System.out.println("android.R.id.home\n\n");
       // super.onBackPressed();
      // getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
        return true;
    }
```

How can i remove current fragment? I've read about back stack, but that approach requires saving fragments in stack using keys. How can i avoid this procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before of fragments on top of each other when I first started using them. I use this code to add fragments:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction =fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = new CustomFragment(); // your fragment to add
transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment,CustomFragment.TAG); // a string in case you need to check with fragment is currently visible.
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

This will ensure that when you press back button the current one will disappear and the one before it will show.

hope it works with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just pop off the back stack, no tracking via keys/tags needed: `FragmentManager.popBackStack()`.  Just use `null` when adding your fragments to the back stack, the system will automatically select a tag for it.

Comment: Yep, i've already found out it. Unfortunately, fragment stays on screen, but with smaller alpha - i can see previous fragment through it

Comment: Sounds like you have something else going on then. If you added a fragment (or replace) and told the transaction to add it to the back stack, a pop will remove it and restore what was previously in the container.